# Unable to import an enum from another class in the same package

Tags: java

I have a a class QueueType:

```
package mypack;

public enum QueueType {
    SMTP, PUT, POST, ISF
}
```

I am trying to import this into another class in the same package but I get an error saying "can't find symbol QueueType". What am I doing wrong?

```
package mypack;

public class RawAsupFile {

    private QueueType queueType;
.
.
.
```

Comment: Where are these files located? Do you use an IDE?

Comment: In the same folder. The the enum part and the RawAsupFile part are in different files within the same folder. The enum part is located in a file called QueueType.java and the other part is in a file called RawAsupFile.java. I was able to compile and get QueueType.class. I cannot compile RawAsupFile.java

Comment: Is the folder called `mypack`? How do you compile the files?

Comment: mypack is a place holder, I have replaced the original value due to privacy reasons. But both the files are in the same package. I compile on the terminal using javac filename.java

Comment: a) the folder structure has to follow the package structure (that's why I asked), b) you have to tell javac where it should try to find classes (aka class path), go one directory up (the root of your package/folder structure) and call `javac -cp . mypackage/Filename.java` (you can also use `*.java` to compile all files in this directory at once)

Comment: The last part worked. I could not compile it individually but going a folder up and compiling them all at once worked for whatever reason

Answer (score 1):

If your files are in the same folder and you want to compile everything together then you can use with option `javac *.java` from folder/package location

In case if you want to compile each file individually then you can try with the command `javac -cp <path location> filename.java`.
Example `javac -cp D:\mypack\* RawAsupFile.java` in Windows